# Как узнать координаты каретки в тексте? (python, Linux)

Tags: python, linux, cursor, координаты

В общем вопрос описан в названии. Как я могу узнать позицию (координаты) курсора на экране. Курсора я имею того, что в тексте. Это нужно для того чтобы открывать окно в этой координате.

Может быть не сразу понятно. Я приведу пример:

У меня есть окно SublimeText3. В нем есть какой то текст:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу получить (x;y) координаты курсора, тот который идет после слова `current` в строке 8.

Я нашел очень много разных способов получить координаты мыши, тобежь самого курсора, который мы передвигаем по экрану а не по тексту

Comment: В общем случае, данная задача не имеет решения, просто потому что далеко не факт, что окошко на экране, в котором стоит курсор - это что-то стандартное, чем можно управлять извне.

Comment: В частых случаях, например, с окнами, которые созданы через GTK, способ [есть](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63834897/is-it-possible-to-get-cursor-coordinates-in-textview-gtk)

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая утилита xdotool и у нее есть команда getmouselocation

Comment: возможно не совсем понятно. Я просто не знаю как еще описать. Эта команда возвращает координаты курсора, как мыши. Мне нужно координаты курсора, который я ставлю в каком-то окне.