# Ошибка с x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ компиляцией

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

Я хочу получить глобальную позицию каретки в системе (координарты). Если не понятно, вот мой еще один вопрос: [мой прошлый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1396181/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-python-linux)

Нашел решение использовать библиотеку `winuser.h`. [Функция в документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcaretpos)

Но мне нужно решение на Linux. Я установил компилятор, который по идее должен поддерживать эту библиотеку. Команда:

```
>>> sudo apt install g++-mingw-w64-x86-64-win32
```

Пытаюсь скомпелировать вот этот код для теста:

```cpp
#include <winuser.h>


int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор возвращает пелену ошибок с самой библиотекой `winuser.h`. Хотя на сколько я понимаю эта библиотека устанавливается вместе с компилятором.

Ошибок очень много вот одна из них:

```
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/winuser.h:41:30: error: typedef ‘WNDPROC’ is initialized (use ‘decltype’ instead)
   41 |   typedef LRESULT (CALLBACK *WNDPROC)(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);
      |                              ^~~~~~~
```

Как мне воспользоваться библиотекой `winuser.h`, а в часности `GetCaretPos`?

Comment: Если пролистать документацию по этой функции до [таблицы с системными требованиями](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcaretpos#requirements), то можно заметить, что там написано: "Целевая платформа: Windows"

Comment: Даже если вы сможете вызывать на линуксе виндавозные функции (для чего вам нужно будет запустить программу через wine), эти функции не смогут взаимодействовать с линуксовыми окошками).